# TestCafe : How to run all tests except few tests

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have few tests that took a considerable long time as few jobs are initiated at the backend side which takes quite long. I want to have some control so that I can run all tests as part of my regression suite except these few long-running tests.

I do not want to specify metadata on all the tests, it would be great if I can add metadata on long-running tests and somehow run all tests except that metadata.

Let's say I add metadata on long-running tests as `longRunning=true` and I can run tests with some command like :
`node node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe  not --test-meta longRunning=true`

Is there any way to execute all tests other than this metadata `longRunning=true`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it (as of December 2020) as part of the command, but you can do it programatically, which is described here: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/testcafe-api/runner/filter.html

Comment: @Jn Neer
Here is a detailed example illustrating to do this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620995/is-it-possible-to-use-the-testcafe-meta-object-to-skip-tests-running-from-the-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620995/is-it-possible-to-use-the-testcafe-meta-object-to-skip-tests-running-from-the-c)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, there is another way provided by TestCafe to skip specific tests, which is the [skip method](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/test/skip.html):

```js
fixture `My test fixture`
.page`https://www.my-test-page-com`;

  test('Test 1', () => {}); // This test will run
  test.skip('Test 2', () => {}); // This test will be skipped
  test('Test 3', () => {}); // This test will run too
```